# "I was first" vs "I was the first"

Tags: grammaticality

> **I was/first to reach/the school/today**

The book describes **I was the first** should be used

I'm not sure about it....
And what is the use of 'today' here!

should it be 'yesterday'?

Comment: What is the actual sentence in the book? Why should it be "yesterday" if talking about something that happened today?

Comment: I was the first to reach the school today. Here, the purpose itself is to highlight one is first, second, or so, which needs an emphasis. Hence, ...the first.... sounds appropriate.

Comment: Can you rewrite this question without using the slashes please? Just expand into multiple lines that you are considering? I can't figure out what the different options are that you are considering.

Comment: For the non-complemented 'I was the first!' and 'I was first!' I'd take these variants to be using the definite article and the (even more definite) null article. 'The first' can certainly take a to-infinitival complement (the first to be born, the first to climb ..., the first to win ...). Dropping the definite article is a well-practised deletion, as over 20 million Google hits for "he was first to" show.

Answer (score 1):

> I was ***the*** first to reach school today.

The idiomatic phrase is ***[to be the first (person) to (do something)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+first+to+do+something)*** where *the first* determines *person* which is omitted. however, in spoken language, "the" is omitted most of the time.

I agree that "to reach school" implies that the person studies or works at that school, but I would add that ***to reach the school***, would need a relative clause particularising "the school":

> I was the first to reach the school ***from the town centre*** today.

Or

> Today, I was the first to reach the school ***where the author of my favourite book teaches***.

Answer (score 0):

> **I was first to  reach   the school  today**
>
> **I was  the  first  to  reach  school  today**

The  OP  seems  to  have  doubts  regarding  the  use  of  the  definite  article  before  first  and  whether  today can be  used  in the  past  tense.

I  think  *I  was  the first  to  reach  school  today*  is   the  better  option if  the speaker  is  studying  in  the  school.

I  am  not  sure  about  I was  first  to  reach.

The  definite  article  **the**  can  be  dropped  if it  is  the  school in which  he  or  she studies.

We  can  use**today**  in the  simple  past  and  in the  present  perfect   for  the  completed  actions  today.